# Pointers in C and casting

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I've started learning pointers this time. Im trying to read bytes from this array. Task is almost done but CLang keep warns me with warning I don't understand. Here's my code. 
Warning says : " Function call argument is an uninitialized value"

```
int main(void)
{
    int tab[] = {67305985,134678021,202050057};
    int *pp=0;
    pp=tab;

    char *wsk=(char*)pp;

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        if((wsk+i)!=(void*)NULL)
            printf("%d ",*(wsk+i));    // warning on this line
        else
            return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: (1) Do not post images of code.  Always post the code you're asking about as text. (2) I see only one warning in the posted image, and it would be easy to convey as text, too.

Comment: Hmm, ok , I'll edit in a second

Comment: I have to disagree with @JohnBollinger, in this specific case. The purpose of posting the image of the code was to show the inline warnings. After the edit, it's far less clear where the uninitialized value warning was being generated. Also, having the image showed another warning that was worth mention that might otherwise have been missed.

Comment: In that case, @Sniggerfardimungus, you should review [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part that says "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.**" (emphasis in the original).

Comment: Not reproduceable -- clang gives no warnings on this code (as long as you stick `#include <stdio.h>` on the top...

Comment: This should fail to compile as `NULL` and `printf` are not defined -- try adding `#include <stdio.h>` to the top

Comment: I'm well aware of the guidelines in this regard, but in this case he posted an image because he needed to provide more than just the code. The way it existed, originally, was far clearer than it is now.

Comment: @Sniggerfardimungus, the way it existed originally may have been *marginally* clearer than the way it is now, but it was *much* harder to work with.  We have good reasons for our expectations of question format, and nothing about this question provides any reason to think it should be an exception.

Comment: `*(wsk+i)` is dereferencing .an address that you do not own if i is greater than 2.

Comment: So how to split my arrray to 12 bytes?

Comment: Not so, @FredK.  Do not overlook that `wsk` is a pointer to *`char`*, not to `int`.

Comment: @John Bollinger Ooops - I missed that, But there is still a problem. When ii >= 8, `printf( "%d ",*(wsk+i));` will reference 4 
bytes, which goes beyond the array  (Assuming it is executed on a machine with 4-byte ints)

Comment: I thought that for a moment too, @FredK, but it also is wrong.  Again, `wsk` is a pointer to `char`, initially pointing to the first of twelve bytes of the representation of `tab`.  `*(wsk+i)` dereferences *one* byte, not four.  The dereference is valid for all values of `i` sampled by the OP's loop. As a variadic argument, the resulting value is then promoted to `int`, and `printf` thus receives an argument that is satisfactory for the `%d` directive.

Answer (score 5):

These warnings are from Clang Static Analyzer (or whatever they call it these days).

It looks like a false positive to me, if we assume that `int` is at least 4 bytes and the real code has `#include <stdio.h>` and no other changes.

If you're using the latest version of the analyzer, you could file a clang bug report. Well -- you could if they allowed people who don't already have accounts to file bug reports.  Maybe someone else reading this thread can do it.

Note: it would help the question to post exactly which version of the analyzer you are running  (this may be different to the compiler you're using to build -- some IDEs use different compilers for building than for these inline messages).

Comment: Im using CLang 3.9

Comment: @Cnewbiec maybe investigate if you can upgrade the version of the compiler used for the messages (i'm not familiar with whatever IDE you are using, so can't give more specific advice there)

Comment: @Cnewbiec ok, maybe see if you can upgrade ,  I googled the documentation of clion with clang-tidy and it talks about using clang 7.0.0 at least .

Comment: Tbh i cannot change CLANG that verification system uses. :D My university has such system where i post my code.

Comment: @Cnewbiec OK. I guess you have no option but to just ignore these messages when they pop up then, or perhaps turn off the analyzer part now and turn it back on from time to time.  Sometimes it will be possible to mangle your code to placate the analyzer although I can't offer any specific suggestions in this case, you could trial-and-error some different variations of code  to do the same thing

Comment: Thank you for help. I think the only option is to ask verifying system manager for help :)

Answer (score 1):

This if statement

```
if((wsk+i)!=(void*)NULL)
```

does not make sense. The macro `NULL` is already a null pointer constant. So there is no sense to cast it to `void *`.

And the pointer `wsk+i` can not be equal to NULL in this loop because initially it points to an object.

Just remove the if statement and output each character in the loop.

And it is a bad idea to use magic numbers like 12 used in the loop.

You could write for example

```
const size_t N = sizeof( tab ) / sizeof( *tab );
```

and then in the loop

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < N * sizeof( int ); i++ )
//...
```

As for the warning then it is irrelative to the presented code provided that you included the header `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: CLang still gives the same warning as in the begginig. I attached Image again .

Comment: @Cnewbiec As I wrote remove the if statement. I can not reproduce the warning.

Comment: Removed, but still. Do you think that I can ignore this warning?

Comment: @Cnewbiec As I said I can not reproduce the warning.

Comment: `sizeof tab` would be simpler than dividing and multiplying again by the same value :)

Comment: @M.M I agree. I used a general approach.

Answer (score 0):

`wsk` will never be null, since you've set it to be the same as `tab` (arrays, in C/C++ are just pointers to a block of data. The warning is telling you that no matter how much you add to `wsk` it will always be non-null. What you need to do is limit your iterations in the loop to the number of valid items in the array, since C/C++ arrays have no terminators of any kind.

The printf might just be confusing CLang. Try `printf("%d ", wsk[i]);`

Comment: Odd. Uh, why not? (The line should work as-is, but in unorthodox enough that it's probably giving CLang a headache.)

Comment: I think that my leader want to teach us ( my group) every details.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers  . They are blocks of data.  You can make pointers to any object (be they arrays or not).

Comment: `printf("%d ", wsk[i])` does not make the warning go away.  The only thing that does (so far) is adding a statement like `printf("%p ", (void *) wsk);` beforehand.